# How to add information simultaneously to a row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a row with 900 records. All of these rows need brackets () around them. Adding brackets to all these records is time consuming, so I was wondering if there is a way to do this all at once.

Do you have ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that your data falls under `A1:B20`. You can enter this formula in `D1`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("("&A1:B20&")")
```

Answer (score 0):

insert another column and put this..

```
=CONCAT("(",B1,")");
```

extend to last row..

Copy this values and use Paste special, and paste as Values Only on designated column...